# Is there a way to get all the variables in flash control in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, actionscript-3, flash

I have a flash control in a windows form. I am wondering if there is a way to get all the variables in it. I know I could probably "guess" (bruteforce) the variables using getValue(variablename), but I'd prefer if there way a way to get the variables without having to guess them.

Comment: I don not think there is way.  That's probably a good thing from a security standpoint.  If you are in control of the swf source files, your can expose any variables you'd like.

Comment: You may just as well decompile the file.

Comment: For AS2 yes, but I don't think getValue(variablename) works in AS3 for private vars and vars not in the documentClass level.  I'm not 100% sure as I haven't used getValue in probably 7 years...

Comment: Have you tried HTTPFox addon to see what data is submited from the form?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with

```
foreach(objectType flashVar in axShockwaveFlash1.FlashVars)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(flashVar.VarName + " = " + flashVar.VarValue);
}
```

Comment: FlashVars is a list of variables? If it is, then this is definitely what I need.

Comment: Wouldn't they already be aware of those, as the flashVars are passed in to the swf from the windows Form that contains it?  I could be wrong, but I don't think this lists internal variables from the swf which is what I think Aghilas Yakoub is looking for

Comment: FlashVars is empty. :( Also, I just saw MediaServices' comment.